# what's up with tensorflow.js MNIST example nextbatch implementation?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, mnist, tensorflow.js

While taking inspiration from the tensorflow.js [Handwritten digit recognition with CNNs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tfjs-training-classfication/index.html), I stumbled upon the following implementation of the nextBatch function in [mnist_data.js](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-tutorials/mnist_data.js):

```
nextBatch(batchSize, data, index) {
  const batchImagesArray = new Float32Array(batchSize * IMAGE_SIZE);
  const batchLabelsArray = new Uint8Array(batchSize * NUM_CLASSES);

  for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
    const idx = index();

    const image =
        data[0].slice(idx * IMAGE_SIZE, idx * IMAGE_SIZE + IMAGE_SIZE);
    batchImagesArray.set(image, i * IMAGE_SIZE);

    const label =
        data[1].slice(idx * NUM_CLASSES, idx * NUM_CLASSES + NUM_CLASSES); // weird part
    batchLabelsArray.set(label, i * NUM_CLASSES);
  }

  const xs = tf.tensor2d(batchImagesArray, [batchSize, IMAGE_SIZE]);
  const labels = tf.tensor2d(batchLabelsArray, [batchSize, NUM_CLASSES]);

  return {xs, labels};
}
```

I understood the point of this function was selecting the images and the corresponding label.
The problem with the provided implementation is that is correctly selecting the corresponding label but also other NUM_CLASSES-1 (10 elements in total) random labels which just happens to be after the selected one.

why is not implemented like the following?

```
nextBatch(batchSize, data, index) {
  const batchImagesArray = new Float32Array(batchSize * IMAGE_SIZE);
  const batchLabelsArray = new Uint8Array(batchSize);

  for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
    const idx = index();

    const image =
        data[0].slice(idx * IMAGE_SIZE, idx * IMAGE_SIZE + IMAGE_SIZE);
    batchImagesArray.set(image, i * IMAGE_SIZE);

    const label = new Uint8Array([data[1][idx]]); // weird part corrected
    batchLabelsArray.set(label, i);
  }

  const xs = tf.tensor2d(batchImagesArray, [batchSize, IMAGE_SIZE]);
  const labels = tf.tensor2d(batchLabelsArray, [batchSize, 1]);

  return {xs, labels};
}
```

I obviously tried to run it with the above implementation, but the model throws the following:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have shape [,10], but got array with shape [1650,1].
    at new e (errors.ts:48)
```

Being the `dense` step implemented as

```
// Our last layer is a dense layer which has 10 output units, one for each
// output class (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).
const NUM_OUTPUT_CLASSES = 10;
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  units: NUM_OUTPUT_CLASSES,
  kernelInitializer: 'varianceScaling',
  activation: 'softmax'
}));
```

Should I be correct, how should I fix the dense layer and the rest of the implementation?
If instead the provided implementation is correct, why does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the shape of the label.

```
const labels = tf.tensor2d(batchLabelsArray, [batchSize, 1]);
```

The labels are created with the most right axis having the shape 1. It should rather be equal to the number of classes there are (ie: 0, 1 ..., 9) which should therefore be 10.

The error is straightforward indicating that the shape should be `[, 10]`.

- create tensor with the shape `[batchSize, 10]`

Obviously if the tensor is created with the shape [batchSize, 10] whereas `batchLabelsArray` has the length `batchSize`, it will throw a shape error. It should rather have the length `batchSize * NUMBER_OF_CLASSES`.

The codelab uses

```
const batchLabelsArray = new Uint8Array(batchSize * NUM_CLASSES);
```

An then to set the class of a certain batchSize it uses the following:

```
for (let i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
      const idx = index();

      const image =
          data[0].slice(idx * IMAGE_SIZE, idx * IMAGE_SIZE + IMAGE_SIZE);
      batchImagesArray.set(image, i * IMAGE_SIZE);

      const label =
          data[1].slice(idx * NUM_CLASSES, idx * NUM_CLASSES + NUM_CLASSES);
      batchLabelsArray.set(label, i * NUM_CLASSES);
    }
```

- The other option is to use `tf.oneHot`:

```js
const labels = tf.oneHot(batchLabelsArray, 10) // batchLabelsArray is an array of batchSize length
```

Comment: sorry, I'm still a bit confused. with a tensor `xs` of size `[batchSize, IMAGE_SIZE]` and a `labels` tensor of size `[batchSize, 10]` wouldn't you end up having 10 labels for each image where only the first one is correct?

Comment: This is the way you create the label tensor. For each feature (image), it has NUMBER_CLASSES values set to 0 except the indice of the correct class which is set to the class value

Comment: understood; so it doesn't matter if the rest of the tensor presents random values/0s/unrelated subsequent labels. what matters is the first element only.

Is there a mathematical explanation behind this or the rest of the labels (and or what results from their interaction) gets just removed by the framework?

Comment: All right, it clicked finally when I printed the MNIST labels! The thing I didn't understand is that the label from the MNIST dataset came "already" one hot encoded. I one hot encoded my raw values and it finally started work! It all make sense now. Thanks for the help!